# Reference for general CSA's

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference, which discusses general Cartan subalgebras (CSA). With general I mean for arbitrary fields and dimensions. For example, Wikipedia states that Cartan subalgebras always exist for finite-dimensional Lie algebras whenever the base field is infinite. But unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any reference, which discusses CSA's in such generality. The standard textbooks usually only cover the specific case of finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebras over alegebraically closed fields with characteristic zero...

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: CSA's are studied in general in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras - chapter III.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bourbaki, *Groupes et Algebres de Lie* (English *Lie Groups and Algebras*), chapter VII, discusses Cartan subalgebras for finite-dimensional Lie algebras over as general fields as possible. That means that in some sections they have to restrict to infinite base fields, sometimes further to characteristic $0$ (and for one section about Lie groups, further to $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ or a complete ultrametric field of charactersitic $0$); but it always says so explicitly at the start of a section. And that is more general than most textbooks do it.

For example, the assertion that every (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra has a CSA if the base field is infinite is Corollary 1 in §2 no.3. (It also says right away that later in §3 it will be proven all CSAs have the same dimension if the base field has zero characteristic.)

---

If you are interested in *infinite-dimensional* Lie algebras, I am not aware of any treatment that discusses both LAs of finite *and* infinite dimension to a significant extent. So you should look at textbooks which already in their title signify they discuss infinite-dimensional ones, the classic being [Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-1382-4) by V. Kac.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!